# Why XCode Clean and Build fix EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: swift, xcode, compiler-construction, exc-bad-access

I've seen lots of people (including me) facing the crash with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with unknown reason. A lot of answers with the solution `clean and build the project` marked as correct.

I'm curious why this happens and how clean and re-build fixed it, but it seems people just don't care and go on with clean-build solution.

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41018210/exc-bad-access-error-for-invoking-method-in-swift) of those `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` with clean-build solution.

In my case, I'm facing something as ridiculous as this:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.childVC.delegate = self // => Crashed EXC_BAD_ACCESS here. Fixed after clean and build
}
```

As far as I know, this happened in Swift a lot more usually than Objective-C. <del>Could it be Swift's features?</del>

Comment: @Moritz yeah, I'm looking for an answer to those mysterious issues in details, less mysterious.

Comment: I had this happen to me today. I didn't want to clean because I didn't want the error to go away at first (because how can I understand it if I can't reproduce it anymore). I eventually cleaned and it went away immediately

Answer (score 4):

These are my thoughts:

Once run, if project is not already built then Xcode generates the required build files in:

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

If the project is not cleaned, either manually or automatically, then the same build files are reused in running apps to reduce consequent build time.

You may have already noticed that Xcode sometimes automatically cleans the build after any major code change. For example, on:

- changing static variables
- changing objective-c code in the swift project

But Xcode still has it's flaws, and sometimes does not clean itself when needed making it possible to run with the, let's say, "broken" build files that eventually give rise to such `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors.

Cleaning it will clear the old build files and new builds don't have the same problem.

Comment: amazing answer, however, I'd like to expand more about those "broken" build. Why are they broken? How do they affect the build and cause `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`?

Comment: I think that the main reason is, that app object pointers addresses to the specific machine memory are changed. Let's say in your example childVC has initial address of 0x27382af, but over time something new is written into this address or this address becomes unavailable and pointer  in build files does not change - so it automatically raises ```EXC_BAD_ACCESS```.

Comment: Do you have any resource or link to back up your answer? It's great but would be much better if there's some related resource about this issue.

Comment: Not really, just usually when I have ```EXC_BAD_ACCESS``` my debugger shows memory address 0x00000000 which is basically nil.
Like I said, these are just my thoughts, I think there are more reasons for this, but this one probably is one of them.

Comment: Then I'm sorry I'll remove the mark accepted answer and would like to wait for other answers as well. It's nothing wrong with yours, just remove it to attract more answers and get more reasons.

Comment: Yep, I will follow this feed too, because it is interesting to me too :D